# Is there a Firefox or Chrome plugin to automatically save images from webpage

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, screen-scraping, file-download

A website has a slideshow of images, for example:[This link](http://www.vogue.fr/defiles/couture-hiver-2011-2012-paris-alexandre-vauthier/5458/diaporama/defile-848/7768/pag)
Since the slideshow is automatic, is there anyway to save those images automatically into a folder?
either by a browser plugin or by some scripting languages ?

btw: The above link is for example ONLY. I WILL NOT do this against that website! I understand the legal issues involved! So please don't discuss the legal issues here

Answer (score 1):

One technical issue is that the method for extracting the image URL (thus makes it possible to download it) will depend between different slideshow-scripts and webpages. I would say that is's almost impossible to make something which works flawlessly on different web pages.

You could take a look at [the iMacros plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-SE/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/), which gives you the ability to automate many browser tasks. Perhaps, you can achieve what you want by creating a macro.

Of course, it's not impossible to make a script or software which downloads all images on a specific web-page, but then you'll have to do it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTTrack](http://HTTrack.com) which allows you to take a snapshot of everything that is on a website. In options you can set custom rules so that you only download files with a specific extension (.jpg, .png, ...). This is a self standing software and not an add-on for a browser, however it is a great tool to have.

Answer (score 0):

[This plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) allow you to extract video and pictures from website. Usefull with Firefox

Answer (score -1):

Just use wget:

```
wget -r -p -L -nc -nH -np -A big.jpg,big.gif,big.png -q http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/image/
```

From here:  http://nullman.net/tutorial/WebScraping.html

In your case, just put file extensions, no need for the "big" part of the filename.

Comment: Your code doesn't work and it's not that simple. I this your code only wokrs when the remote server supports file listing which is very rare .